# Aurelia CLI - au run --watch misses obvious type errors

Tags: aurelia

Using AureliaCLI and TypeScript.
I have a service which returns a specific type and a component which incorrectly assigns the returned object to a variable of another type:

```
import { ItemService } from "./itemService";
import { Item } from '../server/backend';

export class ItemDetails {
   item: Item = null;
   constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {
   }

   activate() {
     this.item = this.itemService.getItem();         
   }
}
```

and

```
import { Seat } from "../server/backend";

export class ItemService {
  item: Seat;
  constructor() {
    this.item = null;
  }

  getItem(){
    return this.item;
  }

  setItem(item: Seat){
    this.item = item;
  }
}
```

This will generate an error when 'au run --watch' is run the first time, but any subsequent change to either file does not produce an error.

Can I configure AureliaCLI to look at dependant files also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right, as you can probably guess, I am new to TypeScript.

I forgot to add a return type to the service method...

This will cause the error to be triggered:

```
  getItem(): Seat {
    return this.item;
  }
```

Comment: Actually, the TS transpiler can normally infer the return type, so I assume there is something else.